# Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler method in controller invoking in success case

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to catch an error scenario but I'm getting an exception in all cases.

Below is my code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/file/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(RestClientException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Not Found")
public void restClientException()
{
  //do nothing
}

public List<myfile> getAllmyfiles() throws RestClientException
{
    return myfileService.getAllmyfiles();
}
```

Comment: post some test or exception. getAllmyfiles() is invoked nowhere, and not annotated with @RequestMapping, please add more context if you wants an answer

Comment: Updated my code.. In success case am getting list of arrays  return Arrays.asList(myfile); but in controller dont know how exceptionhandler is invoking

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@ExceptionHandler(RestClientException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Not Found")
public void restClientException()
{
  //do nothing
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/config/file/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody   
public List<myfile> getAllmyfiles() throws RestClientException
{
    return myfileService.getAllmyfiles();
}
```

you shouldn't use a `@RequestMapping` with an `@ExceptionHandler` : the method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` is automatically invoked when the specified exception is thrown

Comment: aaha.. Thanks lot.. :)